# Visualizing rst diffs with rst2pdf

Tags: diff, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

Is there an easy way to visualize the differences between rst files using [rst2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/)? I know I could use rst2latex instead and then latexdiff to generate PDF files (and that is the effect I am after), but I would like to have the same style in the original and diff files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rst2pdf author here :-)

I don't think you can. However, it's a very cool thing! I think a rst-diff would be a good idea.
It may not work for everything (like, how does latex-diff handle tables where cells are moved around?) for for mostly text ... it *should* be doable.

I may take a shot at it someday.

Comment: I already put together a script that uses wdiff and sed to change the colors of new and deleted text. The one thing missing now is the ability of rst2pdf to strike out text. And you are right, it completely mangles fields, tables and sometimes bulleter lists.

Comment: Actually, this script was a hassle to maintain and had many problems, so I reverted to the rst2latex/latexdiff workflow.